# Regex breaking when encountering slashes

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have a Regex solution that finds and replaces content, it works by finding the start and end, so these two:

```
var start = "/* Start: User One */", end = "/* End: User One */";
```

Then I have a userCSS variable and a newContent, newContent replaces everything within userCSS. It works completely fine without any quotations, but when a quotation is in the mix it's breaking.

I feel like I need to escape these slashes but I'm not quite sure how.

**Here are two examples that should explain what I'm struggling with:**

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xxuqv30t/

Broken fiddle with quotations (single and double): https://jsfiddle.net/samfahav/

Example adding `background: url('/bg.jpg');` breaks the Regex.

**What I'm looking for: how do I escape the quotations with my current Regex solution?**

```
var quote = function(str) {
        return str.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]/(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
    };

var re = new RegExp(quote(start) + "[^/]+" + quote(end));
var newCss = userCSS.replace(re, newContent);
```

I'm thinking the Regex is looking for the start and end and when it trys going through and hit's a quotation it falls back and fails.

**Edit:** It seems the slashes are breaking it, not the quotations/brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You are escaping your backslash in the regex.

You currently have `([.?*+^$[\]/(){}|-])`
and it should be `([.?*+^$[\]\/(){}|-])`.

Without escaping that backslash the regex with through and error cause its not an accepted format.

Comment: I tried that earlier, but I seem to have it working removing the backslash from the middle part of the Regex, so instead of having the backslash in the var re, I've removed it: var re = new RegExp(quote(start) + "[^]+" + quote(end)); and it seems to work. Hopefully there's no security implications? @m_callens